# How to install Unmanaged Package from URL

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I created my own Unmanaged Package on a test sandbox. I would like to install the package on another sandbox now, but I am not able to see where to do this from. I have produced the Installation URL. I go to Setup -> Installed Packages and I can see that the only way to install packages is from the AppExchange. Is there a button or something I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just navigate to that installation URL and it should install fine. I don't know where you saw that you can only install packages that are listed on the AppExchange. In the original sandbox, when you made the package, it created an installation URL on each version. Just navigate there and sign into the other sandbox.

Oh, **substitute "test" for "login**" in the installation URL. That way you can put it into a sandbox and not production.

Comment: Substitution worked. However, I am receiving an error:

Duplicate Name The name "ABCDEFG_H__c.DeviceId" is already used on component type: Custom Field Definition. Please rename existing component

Do you have an idea of what this could mean?

Comment: It means that you have a field in your org that is also in the package. You will need to delete or rename the existing field. You may have the opportunity to rename the new field, but that's not recommended. Because it's a sandbox, rename/remove the old one and reload any data into the installed field of the same name.

Comment: I've been reading that this is the exact method of doing this, but I am not sure I understand correctly the meaning behind it. Isn't the point of having two organisations - one staging and one for production, exactly that - we have the same objects, fields etc. so once I develop a page in staging I could deploy easily in production. Moreover, if I delete a field in production, isn't this going to interfere with the whole setup so far? I am lost

Comment: Please do the Trailhead modules related to this. You're asking some very basic - but not easy to answer in this forum - questions.

Comment: Sure, can you point me to a name of the Trailhead, please. Thank you

Comment: Seriously? Do a search on Trailhead or actually do some of the work for yourself. I'm not going to keep this conversation going. This community requires that people show initiative. Spoon feeding is not encouraged.